# Different ld-json LocalBusiness schema on each subpage

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I have a company  with different local services.
Is it a good practice to put LocalBusiness schema for each service subpage like this:

```
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "LocalBusiness",
"name" : "Service 1 title",
"description": "service 1 description",
"image" : [ "https://mywebsitehere.com/images/service_1.jpg"],
"url" : "https://mywebsitehere.com/offer/service_1/",
```

and next services like:

```
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "LocalBusiness",
"name" : "Service 2 title",
"description": "service 2 description",
"image" : [ "https://mywebsitehere.com/images/service_2.jpg"],
"url" : "https://mywebsitehere.com/offer/service_2/",
```

All other properties like: Address, Geo, Phone, Email, Logo, OpeningHours, hasMap etc will be the same for all subpages.
Will these ld-json schemas help with gaining google rich snippets for my website services pages?

Comment: You should use `@id`s and reuse (link) the common specifications to each `@LocalBusiness` `@id`.
You can validate here: https://validator.schema.org/.
`Rich Snippets` is a very small subset of `schema.org` and should not limit your representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not support structured data for services for **[rich snippets](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/search-gallery)**. However, this does not mean that Google will simply discard your (presumably relevant) structured data. This data may work for voice searches and maybe scraped by the Google Knowledge Graph API.

**[Google requires](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/sd-policies#relevance)** structured data to represent each separate content that the data refers to:

> Your structured data must be a true representation of the page
> content.

Thus, if your web page content represents a local business, use the type `LocalBusiness`. The same applies to the page providing the service.